# check whether text field is empty or not jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which contain lots of `input[type=text]` fields. I want to put a check that user must have fill all the fields otherwise show error message. For this i tried :

```
if ($('div').children("input[type=text]").attr("value") == '') 
 flag = false; 
else 
 flag = true;
```

But this will not check all the text field, it only checks the first-child . How can i check all the text field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead

```
 if ($('div').find("input[type=text]").val() == '')
```

To check over all input items you need to iterate over them using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Correct code would be:

```
$(function() {
    $('input:submit').click(function(){
        var flag = true;
        $('div').find("input[type=text]").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() === '') flag = false
        });

        alert(flag);
    });
});​
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/QH36p/1/) on jsFiddle.

This code return `true` if all `input[type=text]` fields inside `div` are filled and `false` if at least one is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way

```
if(!$('div').find('#idOfTextField').val()){
 //empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("div").find('input:text[value=""]').length > 0)
{
 alert("error");
 return false;
}
```